# I can not embed my GWT application in HTML page

Tags: gwt

I'm new with GWT, at the begging of my work I tried to embed my GWT application in HTML page it works... The steps I followed is that I give the RootPanel in the entrypoint class an id (e. G: `RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get("stockList")`) and call that `id(stockList)` in a div tag in my html page(e.g:`<div id="stockList"></div>`)

At first it works... but now and suddenly it doesn't really I can't figure the problem tried many ways in this simple issue but all in *vain!*

Can any one help solving this issue?

Comment: What changed between the time it worked and the time it didn't work? Are there any error messages? Are you sure there aren't any error messages? Did you check the server console, the log files, the browser (even the little error icons that you might normally ignore), the browser's console, FireBug or other browser developer tools? What version of GWT are you using? What browser? Does it work in any other browser? Dev mode or Web mode?

Comment: One thing I've noted repeatedly (generally with HTML, not just with GWT) is, that empty `<div>`s often cause strange problems, depending on the browser. You might want to try, if changing the HTML element e.g. to `<div id="stockList">&nbsp;</div>` helps.

Answer (score 0):

check whether you have removed on jo-cache javascript link line by any chance
or
check you have the stockList content in DIV using firebug addon (Firefox stuff) if you find it probably it's in hidden

check stockList container's parent display is block
most probably it should work with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try running after

1. Clearing browser cache
2. Cleaning Project